# Maven groupId and package name in java source

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

If I have a maven groupid com.mycompany.app, does it mean I need to name my package 
under the name of com.mycompany.app.*?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, maven doesn't care what package names you use. Having said that, it's not a bad idea to make them consistent to make it a little easier to see which dependency a class comes from.

Answer (score 5):

While creating a maven project if you have mentioned values for both `groupId` and package name, then maven will consider the package name to place your java class.

For example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=gen.src -DartifactId=Iftekhar -DpackageName=com.src.Model -Dversion=2.0-Snapshot
```

In the above scenario `App.java` class will be created inside the package `com.src.Model` and the `groupId` value will not be considered.

But if you have mentioned only `groupId` value (and not package name) like below:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.src.Controller -DartifactId=Iftekhar -Dversion=2.0-Snapshot
```

Then `App.java` class will be created inside the package `com.src.Controller`.